# SQL Query - Queries involving AVG of COUNT and queries involving dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, count, oracle-xe

My Databases look like so:

**PEAK (NAME, ELEV, DIFF, MAP, REGION)**
**CLIMBER (NAME, SEX)**
**PARTICIPATED (TRIP_ID, NAME)**
**CLIMBED (TRIP_ID, PEAK, WHEN)**

- PEAK gives info about the mountain peaks that the user is interested in. The table lists the name of each peak, it elevation(in ft), its difficulty level(on a scale of 1-5), the map that it is located on, and the region of the Sierra Nevada that it is located in.
- CLIMBER lists the members of club, and gives their name and gender.
- PARTICIPATED gives the set of climbers who participated in each of the various climbing trips. The number of participants in each trip varies.
- CLIMBED tells which peaks were climbed on each climbing trip, along w/ the data that each peak was climbed.

I need help w/ writing an SQL query for these 2 example scenarios:

- Compute the average number of peaks scaled by the men in the club and by the women in the club.
- Which people have climbed every single peak that Maria has climbed?
- Who has climbed more than 20 peaks in some 60 day span?

**EDIT**: First query now works and looks like this:

```
SELECT SEX, AVG(num_peaks) AS avg_peaks
FROM 
   (
    SELECT CLIMBER.*, COUNT(CLIMBED.PEAK) num_peaks
    FROM CLIMBED
    INNER JOIN PARTICIPATED
    ON PARTICIPATED.TRIP_ID = CLIMBED.TRIP_ID
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN CLIMBER
    ON CLIMBER.NAME = PARTICIPATED.NAME
    GROUP BY CLIMBER.NAME, CLIMBER.SEX
  )
GROUP BY SEX;
```

This query gives me the overall number of peaks climbed my males, and females. But I can't seem to figure out how to get the averages instead of the counts. I know you can't just simply change the COUNT function to AVG b/c my data is in the string form and not integer.

My second query looks like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PARTICIPATED.NAME
FROM PARTICIPATED
INNER JOIN CLIMBED
ON PARTICIPATED.TRIP_ID = CLIMBED.TRIP_ID
WHERE CLIMBED.PEAK IN
    (
     SELECT CLIMBED.PEAK
     FROM CLIMBED
     INNER JOIN PARTICIPATED
     ON PARTICIPATED.TRIP_ID = CLIMBED.TRIP_ID
     WHERE NAME IN ('MARIA')
    )
AND PARTICIPATED.NAME NOT IN ('MARIA');
```

The query gives me all of the people that have climbed a peak that Maria has also climbed, but doesn't give me just the people that have climbed **every** single peak that Maria has climbed. Not sure how to filter out the rest of the people in this way.

And lastly my final query looks like so:

```
SELECT PARTICIPATED.NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT CLIMBED.PEAK)
FROM PARTICIPATED
LEFT JOIN CLIMBED
ON CLIMBED.TRIP_ID = PARTICIPATED.TRIP_ID
GROUP BY PARTICIPATED.NAME;
```

This query gives all of the climbers names and the total number of peaks that they have each climbed, but I have no clue on how to filter it even more so that it only shows people that have climbed 20+ peaks within a 60 day span.
I tried using

```
HAVING CLIMBED.WHEN BETWEEN -60 AND 60;
```

but that doesn't work.

Any help is much appreciated, and I'm using Oracle Express as my DB.

Comment: You have already posted this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437653/sql-query-average-climbed-and-pair-that-has-climbed-the-most-peaks)

Comment: Not a response to your whole question. But your second query should have `WHERE CLIMBED.PEAK = ALL (... WHERE NAME = 'MARIA') AND NAME <> 'MARIA'`. Using `IN` is equivalent to = ANY(...), but you need all of the peaks, not just one. Also, it is pointless to use IN for single values, use = and <> instead. And you have an extra semicolon.
See [this post about ORACLE and ANY, ALL, and SOME](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql).

Answer (score 0):

I precise I work on SQL server, so I searched on the internet for oracle syntax, there might  be some errors, but I think it is ok.

Concerning your first query, my idea would be to do a subquery, which is going to count the number of peaks climbed by each participant, and then take the average on each sex. I use the `with` syntax to be as clear as possible, to separate the subquery.

```
WITH TABLE_COUNT AS
( SELECT COUNT(CLIMBED.PEAK) AS NUMBER_CLIMBED,
CLIMBER.SEX,
CLIMBER.NAME
FROM CLIMBED
INNER JOIN PARTICIPATED
ON PARTICIPATED.TRIP_ID = CLIMBED.TRIP_ID
INNER JOIN CLIMBER
ON CLIMBER.NAME = PARTICIPATED.NAME
GROUP BY CLIMBER.SEX, CLIMBER.NAME;
)
SELECT AVG(NUMBER_CLIMBED),
SEX
FROM TABLE_COUNT
GROUP BY SEX
```

Then, concerning your second query, I would think it another way. I would have a table with every climber, and a line for each pit Maria has climbed. If a pit Maria climbed is not climbed by the climber, then a column would have `1`as value, otherwise `0`. If the sum is zero, then the climber climbed all peaks Maria did climb.

Let's first select every pit Maria climbed, and in another table every peak climbed by others, then use a `LEFT JOIN` to join them; I don't know if you know how it works, but it would give a `NULL` value if the peak was not climbed, which is what we look for. It will only give peaks climbed by Maria, not the other ones. I use  group by in the `TABLE_PARTICIPER` to avoid having too many lines, but it is not necessary.

```
WITH TABLE_MARIA AS 
(
 SELECT CLIMBED.PEAK
 FROM CLIMBED
 INNER JOIN PARTICIPATED
 ON PARTICIPATED.TRIP_ID = CLIMBED.TRIP_ID
 WHERE NAME IN ('MARIA')
),

 TABLE_PARTICIPER AS 
( 
 SELECT CLIMBED.PEAK,
 NAME
 FROM CLIMBED
 INNER JOIN PARTICIPATED
 ON PARTICIPATED.TRIP_ID = CLIMBED.TRIP_ID
 WHERE NAME NOT IN ('MARIA')
 GROUP BY NAME,
 CLIMBED.PEAK
)
```

Now I wil subquery the table with every peak climbed by Maria, every name of other participers and the peak if they climbed it, `NULL` if they didn't, and then select them  with the having function.

```
SELECT NAME
FROM (
SELECT TABLE_MARIA.PEAK AS MARIA_PEAK,
TABLE_PARTICIPER.PEAK AS PARTICIPER_PEAK,
TABLE_PARTICIPER.NAME
FROM TABLE_MARIA
LEFT JOIN TABLE_PARTICIPER ON TABLE_MARIA.PEAK = TABLE_PARTICIPER.PEAK
) AS QUERY
GROUP BY NAME HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN PARTICIPER_PEAK IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

And this should work perfectly. Tell me if there is a problem.

Concerning the last query, we can do something "dirty". Let's have a table with every climber, every peak they climbed at every date, and left join it with itself to have a lot of rows for each climber for each date, to know how many peaks he climbed in the 60 days ahead of this date. then we can count for each climber and date the number of rows, and take only climbers for which the count is Superior of 20.

```
WITH TABLE_PEAKS AS 
(
SELECT CLIMBED.PEAK,
 CLIMBED.WHEN,
 PARTICIPATED.NAME
 FROM CLIMBED
 INNER JOIN PARTICIPATED
 ON PARTICIPATED.TRIP_ID = CLIMBED.TRIP_ID
)

SELECT DISTINCT NAME
FROM (
SELECT T1.NAME
FROM TABLE_PEAKS T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_PEAKS T2 ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME AND 
(T2.WHEN > T1.WHEN OR (T2.WHEN=T1.WHEN AND T2.PEAK <>T1.PEAK)) 
AND NOT (T2.WHEN > ADDDATE(T1.WHEN,60))
) AS QUERY
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) > 20
```

Tell me if you have problems !

Comment: I've got the first one figured out now, but the second query I'm not sure how to piece your answer together to get a working query for it.

Comment: Oups, sorry, i forgot a comma between the two with clauses, my answer is edited. Sorry !

Comment: I have a question for your third question, do you mean people who climbed 20 different peaks in 60 days, or 20 peaks evenf if there is 3 times the same peak ? And is it 60 days, or 120 days (60 days before or after a given date ) ?

Comment: 20 peaks as in total, same peaks are fine. And I would think 120 days as ( 60 days before or after a given date) as long as the person who is queryed climbed 20 peaks in any 60 day span.

Comment: Also for the first query I'm getting invalid table name error on line 9: WITH table_participer AS

Comment: Ok, I have a solution I am going to write it in comment. It is not optimised at all but should work. The idea is to have a table with a row each time a climber climbs a peak with the date, and left join it with itself only for date superior at the date on the line, and not superior of 60 days. Then you count the number of rows for one date for one climber, group by climber and date and you know if at least once he climbed more than 20 peaks. I edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, it was again a typo error, you shouldn't have twice with, but just `with table1 as ( bla bla), table2 as (bla bla)`

Comment: I also don't know if in one trip you can have more than one peak ; the constrain `OR (T2.DATE=T1.DATE AND T2.PEAK <>T1.PEAK)` allows one trip to have different peaks, but still count all of them.

Comment: So ? Does it work ? Could you validate the answer if it does ?